# Javascript text field

Tags: javascript, html

Problem:

Using an event listener, I'm looking to have the values in the text fields show up in the corresponding divs when the button is clicked. "[object HTMLInputElement]" 
is showing up in the divs when the button is clicked. I think that the textOne variable is holding the text field itself and not its contents. How can i fix this?

html:

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="textOne" value="one"/><br>
<input type="text" id="textTwo" value="two"/><br>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Enter"/><br>
textOne: <div id="one" style="width: 100px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid black;"></div><br>
textTwo: 
<div id="two" style="width: 100px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid black;"></div>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
var divOne = document.getElementById("one");
var divTwo = document.getElementById("two");
var textOne = document.getElementById("textOne");
var textTwo = document.getElementById("textTwo"); 
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

function inDiv() {

    divOne.innerHTML = textOne;
    divTwo.innerHTML = textTwo;
}

btn.addEventListener("click", inDiv);
```

Comment: divOne etc are HTMLInputElement's ... you need their "value" property

Answer (score 1):

You need to access their values. Use `.value` property to access their values. With `getElementById` you get the whole `HTMLElement` as object, in your case `HTMLInputElement`. You can access many other properties of that object.

```js
var divOne = document.getElementById("one");
var divTwo = document.getElementById("two");
var textOne = document.getElementById("textOne");
var textTwo = document.getElementById("textTwo"); 
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

function inDiv() {

    divOne.innerHTML = textOne.value;
    divTwo.innerHTML = textTwo.value;
}

btn.addEventListener("click", inDiv);
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" id="textOne" value="one"/><br>
<input type="text" id="textTwo" value="two"/><br>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Enter"/><br>
textOne: <div id="one" style="width: 100px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid black;"></div><br>
textTwo: 
<div id="two" style="width: 100px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid black;"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think that the textOne variable is holding the text field itself
>   and not its contents.

No, it doesn't.
`document.getElementById("one");` returns the html element input itself.
To get its`value`, refer the `value` property of this input :

```
var value = document.getElementById("one").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var one = document.getElementById("one");
var two = document.getElementById("two");
var inp1 = document.getElementById("textOne");
var inp2 = document.getElementById("textTwo");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
one.innerHTML = inp1.value;
two.innerHTML = inp2.value;
})
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" id="textOne" value="one"/><br>
<input type="text" id="textTwo" value="two"/><br>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Enter"/><br>
textOne: <div id="one" style="width: 100px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid black;"></div><br>
textTwo: 
<div id="two" style="width: 100px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid black;"></div>
</form>
```